How to replace each() in `if-statement` (each() is deprecated in PHP 8)
I try to keep an old PHP application running, and I need to upgrade from PHP 7 to PHP 8. I replaced a lot each() with  foreach() easily, but I stumble on this code (I am not PHP programmer):
if (!(list($k, $this->varsRun[$dynName]) = @each($this->arBlockV[$dynName])) ||
$this->varsRun[$dynName] == 'end')
{
array_pop($this->arBlockC);
return false;
} 

I saw posts on SO suggest to reimplement each function, but I am not sure if this is the right approach.
I tried solution suggested at How can I update code that uses the deprecated each() function?, but it does not cover each in if-statement. My attempt does not work correctly:
$k = key($this->arBlockV[$dynName]);
$this->varsRun[$dynName] = current($this->arBlockV[$dynName]);
if (!$k || $this->varsRun[$dynName] == 'end')
    {
    array_pop($this->arBlockC);
    return false;
}

Any idea how-to replace each in this case properly?
